# List thread-local variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

We can assign a thread-local variable on Ruby, like so:

```
Thread.current[:foo] = 1
Thread.current[:bar] = 2
```

But how do we list / enumerate those variables at a later time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the keys using [`Thread#keys`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Thread/keys):

```
Thread.current[:foo] = 1
Thread.current[:bar] = 2
Thread.current.keys  # => [:__recursive_key__, :foo, :bar]
```

Don't know how that's helpful though, because you should know which keys you use.

Comment: This will only tell you the keys used by each thread when running in the thread.  If you want all keys for all threads, you'd have to write extra code to accumulate them in non-local storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Thread.list.each { |t|
   p "T #{t.object_id} tvars:#{t.thread_variables.length} numkeys:#{t.keys.length}"
 }
```

Comment: @AlexKM Some explanation here... It loops through each thread and prints a line containing thread ID, the number of thread variables, and the number of Fiber variables (those set with Thread.current[:some_key].